# RTP server on embedded device and client on Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, embedded, rtp

I have an embedded device which has Wifi and Audio capabilities. I want to make my Android phone communicate to it using RTP. I have already tried Mobile to Mobile RTP audio communications. That works like charm. But now I want to try, one side Android and other side this embedded device. Could anyone point me to the source code (simple one as less RAM in embedded device) of basic RTP.

I am using ffmpeg on Windows PC to simulate the embedded device. When I "join()" the RTP from my Android, I get the error as 0x64 wrong protocol type.

If I get a basic handshake between the devices for audio, it will be great.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.